# Long text causes inline element to display below

Tags: css, responsive-design, response, word-wrap

I have to inline-block elements. I want to display side by side the two elements. When the text of the link in the second block element displays on two lines because of a long text (word wrap), the link parent element displays on the second line.

In the fiddle bellow the second `div.job_content` block should display like the first one (side by side).

Any Idea?

Here is the fiddle:

```css
.content {
  width: 300px;
}

.job-content {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.job-thumbnail {
  display: inline-block;
}

.job-thumbnail img {
  margin: 10px 10px 5px;
  max-width: none;
  border: none;
}

.job-title {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="job-content">
    <div class="job-thumbnail">
      <img width="80" height="80" src="http://www.rockstargames.com/midnightclubLA/downloads/content/avatar/MCLA_avatar_256x256_black_rlogo.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="job-title">
      <a href="" title="Permalien vers Inspecteur(trice) du permis de conduire et de la sécurité routière" rel="bookmark">Small text</a>

      <dl class="">
        <dt class="study_level">Niveau requis:</dt>
        <dd>
          <a href="#" rel="tag">bac ou équivalent</a>
        </dd>
      </dl>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="job-content">
    <div class="job-thumbnail">
      <img width="80" height="80" src="http://www.rockstargames.com/midnightclubLA/downloads/content/avatar/MCLA_avatar_256x256_black_rlogo.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="job-title">
      <a href="" title="Permalien vers Inspecteur(trice) du permis de conduire et de la sécurité routière" rel="bookmark">Large text du permis de conduire et de la
                    sécurité routière</a>

      <dl class="">
        <dt class="study_level">Niveau requis:</dt>
        <dd>
          <a href="#" rel="tag">bac ou équivalent</a>
        </dd>
      </dl>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a much more simple example:

```css
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;   
}
.thumbnail {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -80px;
    width: 80px;        
}
.text {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: auto;
    padding-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img width="80" height="80" class="thumbnail" src="http://www.rockstargames.com/midnightclubLA/downloads/content/avatar/MCLA_avatar_256x256_black_rlogo.jpg">
  <a href="#" class="text">
    This text shouldn't be pushed downwards when the "result" frame is resized
  </a>
</div>
```

Simply resize the result frame to see the text being pushed downwards... I have this done this before, I don't get what is wrong...

Comment: Your question is not so clear.

Comment: I edited the question. Sorry for my bad english on that issue ...

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DxTg2/7/)

```
.content {
    width: 700px;  
}
.job-content {
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;   
    margin: 20px 0;     
}
.job-thumbnail {
    display: inline-block;  
}

.job-thumbnail img {
    margin: 10px 10px 5px;
    max-width: none;
    border: none;
}
.job-title {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width:190px;
}
```

Comment: I've edited my answer and the jsfiddle link, so I hope this is what you need

Comment: It is nearly that except that the two .job-content should be one under the other and the .job-content width should be able to vary (Responsive design). So fixing the .job-title width does do the job...

Comment: Really I don't get why in my example when the text in the link element is "long enough" to display on two lines, the parent element is pushed bellow ...

Comment: Here is a much simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/DxTg2/11/

Simply resize the result frame to see the text being pushed downwards

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you're running with inline-block?

If you float the elements it is much easier to do - http://jsbin.com/ojoloq/1/edit

**UPDATE**

Remove the inline-block and use floats will do the trick (http://jsfiddle.net/DxTg2/12/)

```
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
float:left;            
}
.thumbnail {
    float:left;
   margin-right: -80px;
    width: 80px;        
}

.text {
    float:left;
vertical-align: top;
    width: auto;
    padding-left: 80px;
}
```

Comment: The images have a fixed width. So the percentage & float approach doesn't do the trick...